# PHP Unix minutes without 60min cycle

Tags: php, unix

I have a problem. I have like a UNIX timestamp stored in my database. For example '1515116587' . Now I try to get, how many minutes this was ago. I wrote a code, but it repeats every hour. So the cycle is only until 60 minutes. I need it without a cycle. Like "77 mins ago". When something is 77 mins ago, it gives me 17 minutes ago, instead of 77 minutes ago. Can somebody help?

```
$date = new DateTime();
$timenow = $date->getTimestamp();
$timelog = $row->cartposted;
$seconds = $timenow - $timelog;
$min = intval(($seconds / 60) % 60);
```

Comment: Remove the `% 60` part - that's what's calculating the remainder

Comment: I really don't want to be mean, but maybe try learning some basic math before starting programming? :D `%` is modulo.